# Buscar texto y comparar con un numero

Tags: c#, selenium

Quiero buscar un texto y compararlo con un número, si es más alto que un número así, ejecute un if y si es más bajo un else

```
 string sato = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".user_reward_points")).Text;
 if (sato > 1200)
 {
     driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#free_points_rewards > .effect2:nth-child(2) .large-3:nth-child(3) > .reward_link_redeem_button_style")).Click();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que convertir primero la string que contiene `sato` a un valor numérico para poder compararlo como quieres

puedes usar el método `TryParse` para convertirlo y manejar un error en caso que no se pueda convertir

```
int satoInt;
if (int.TryParse(sato, out sato))
{
    if (sato > 1200)
    {
      driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#free_points_rewards > .effect2:nth-child(2) .large-3:nth-child(3) > .reward_link_redeem_button_style")).Click();
    }
    else
    {
        //Haz otra cosa
    }
}
else
{
     //Handler para el error al convertir el campo sato a int
}
```